# I need help grouping data

Tags: python, numbers, grouping, storage

i have got this far. when i run it, it turns the string numbers into floats and even gets rid of the time stamps for me. how then do i take these numbers and put them in new groups? what my goal is, is i want each line to be its own list but only the numbers between the time stamps and the last 0 of each line.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

ver = '''
 2018.12.0400:00,0.73572,0.73614,0.73544,0.73550,520,0
2018.12.0401:00,0.73550,0.73594,0.73545,0.73553,1181,0
2018.12.0402:00,0.73553,0.73606,0.73510,0.73539,1960,0
2018.12.0403:00,0.73539,0.73621,0.73481,0.73608,2898,0


'''
number = ver.split(',')

for num in number:
    try:
        new = float(num)
        print(new)
    except:
        print('this one messed up')
```

Comment: Couldn't quite understand what you meant by grouping. Could you please include the expected output as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could split the data by line first then split by ',' again.

```
ver = '''2018.12.0400:00,0.73572,0.73614,0.73544,0.73550,520,0
2018.12.0401:00,0.73550,0.73594,0.73545,0.73553,1181,0
2018.12.0402:00,0.73553,0.73606,0.73510,0.73539,1960,0
2018.12.0403:00,0.73539,0.73621,0.73481,0.73608,2898,0'''
ver = [i.split(',') for i in ver.split('\n')]

df = pd.DataFrame(ver)
df
```

output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   2018.12.0400:00 0.73572 0.73614 0.73544 0.73550 520 0
1   2018.12.0401:00 0.73550 0.73594 0.73545 0.73553 1181    0
2   2018.12.0402:00 0.73553 0.73606 0.73510 0.73539 1960    0
3   2018.12.0403:00 0.73539 0.73621 0.73481 0.73608 2898    0
```